# MySQL - If exists, get primary key. Else, add entry

Tags: mysql

My table has two columns: "id" (Auto Increment, Primary) and "number" (Unique). Now I want to the following:

- if the number already exists, return the id;
- else, add entry to the table and return its id.

What's the most efficient method to do this job?

Note:

- There is a greater probability that the number is new;
- The table will contain hundreds of thousands of records.

Thank you!

Comment: the best way I can think of is with a stored procedure, I can't provide an example right now, but take a look at it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table (number) VALUES (42);

SELECT id FROM table WHERE number = 42;
```

That's probably the most efficient in MySQL. You could use a Stored Procedure to lump them up, which may or may not be slightly more efficient.

EDIT:

If you think it's going to be rare that new numbers come up, this will be even faster:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE number = 42;

if (!id) {

  INSERT INTO table WHERE number = 42;
  id = SELECT @LAST_INSERT_ID;

}
```

There is a possible race condition here if concurrent threads simultaneously select then insert the same number at the same time. In this case, the later insert will fail. You could recover from this by re-selecting on this error condition.

Comment: I have updated my question. There would be hundreds of thousands of records in the table and there would be a greater probability of getting a new number. How much difference would a stored procedure create for that many records?

Comment: In that case I would do the insert then the select, it's simpler and there is no race condition. Assuming your database server is near your web server, the stored procedure will make little difference. You could test this easily by writing both code paths and then stress testing them.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one such stored function that does what you describe:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `spNextNumber`(pNumber int) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
DECLARE returnValue int;
SET returnValue := (SELECT Number FROM Tbl WHERE Number = pNumber LIMIT 1);
IF returnValue IS NULL THEN
    INSERT IGNORE INTO Tbl (Number) VALUES (pNumber);
    SET returnValue := pNumber; -- LAST_INSERT_ID() can give you the real, surrogate key
END IF;
RETURN returnValue;
END
```

Comment: How about using this:

INSERT IGNORE INTO People (Number) VALUES (pNumber);
SET returnValue := (SELECT Number FROM People WHERE Number = pNumber LIMIT 1);

I guess that would be more efficient?

Comment: it will depend on the frequency of duplicates, as Chris mentions above.... attempting an unnecessary insert and catching with IGNORE is probably going to be more costly than a select...limit 1.  However, to his point about the race condition I've added an IGNORE to the insert in this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help Tahbaza! I have revised my question and added a bit more details, can you please confirm if your solution is still the best or would you like to revise it?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but it is a common problem.  So, for the sake of anyone searching for a solution here are 4 different ways to accomplish this task with performance benchmarks.  http://mikefenwick.com/blog/insert-into-database-or-return-id-of-duplicate-row-in-mysql/.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20150915085727/http://mikefenwick.com:80/blog/insert-into-database-or-return-id-of-duplicate-row-in-mysql/